Keep first Element in python Flet ListView object when Scrolling down
Referencing to this Post, the given answer works for me but i would like to always see the colum labels of the DataTable object. Right now if i scroll down, the first row, including the header disappears.
I tried to append only the Rows of the DataTable Object to the ListView Object but partialy appending an Object gives me an Error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
